# Make SPARQL queries for reviews

Tags: sparql, endpoint

i'm trying to find the way to collect all the things that have this property:

```
"http://purl.org/stuff/rev#hasReview"
```

So I tryed to do this query on the
http://sparql.sindice.com/ endpoint:

```
PREFIX rev: <http://purl.org/stuff/rev#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT *
WHERE
{
 ?thing rev:hasReview ?review .
}
```

And the result was just a few, I think that if you don't provide the uri graph, it will search on his own graph. Is it on that way?
And my other doubt is, how can I know which is the graph uri from http://revyu.com/ for example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query gets the graph:

```
PREFIX rev: <http://purl.org/stuff/rev#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * WHERE {
  {  GRAPH ?graph { ?thing rev:hasReview ?review . } }
}
```

In case you also want to get the triples in the default graph, you can use:

```
PREFIX rev: <http://purl.org/stuff/rev#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * WHERE {
  {  GRAPH ?graph { ?thing rev:hasReview ?review . } }
 UNION 
  {  ?thing rev:hasReview ?review . }
}
```